# C++ Error: type name is not allowed array

Tags: c++, arrays

```
class Zombie
{
    public:
        Zombie();
        Zombie(int howTall);
        Zombie(int howTall, int howHeavy);
        int getHeight();
    private:
        int height;
        int weight;
};

Zombie::Zombie()
{
    height = 6;
    weight = 180;
}

int main()
{
    Zombie army[4];

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        army[i] = Zombie;

}
```

Why do I get the error when I try to set army[i] = Zombie? Army is an array of Zombies and I already wrote a default constructor for the Zombie class. when I replace Zombie with Zombie(), the code works, but shouldn't omitting the () call the default constructor as well?

Not shown: the other constructors and methods are implemented already.

I know that if I declare army to be an array of pointers to Zombies and do army[i] = new Zombie it will work, but I don't know why the above code doesn't.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```
Zombie army[4];
```

You are already constructing 4 Zombies of height 6 and weight 180. The default constructor is being called 4 times (try to add a call to `std::cout` in it and you'll see!).

Therefore what you are attempting to do in your loop **is not needed**, unless you *want* (for whatever reason), to construct new zombies *again*. In which case, the proper syntax would be:

```
army[i] = Zombie();
```

Comment: Ah, random downvotes with no explanation, you make my day. *throws a rock at some innocent bypasser for no reason*

Comment: Naw, you're purrfect.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're trying to assign a type and not an object of that type.

Besides that you have already the objects in army, you would only need to assign a new object now, when you want to overwrite the values with 'new Zombies'